# Add existing shared project, not added to source control

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, shared-project

I have some shared projects which I use in a lot of other projects. My workflow for a new project is like this:

1. Create blank VS solution (check "Add to Source Control" in the New Project dialog)
2. Paste shared project folders into the solution folder
3. Add the shared projects to the solution by right-clicking the solution in VS, then selecting Add -> Existing Project and selecting the shproj-file of the pasted shared project

The shared project is now added to the VS solution, but it's not added to source control. Is there anything I can do to automatically add this project type to source control?

Adding an existing project of another type automatically adds it to source control. I expected it to behave the same for shared projects.